# ESXi remote access

Tags: esxi

i have a server with ESXi in my local network.
i can connect to it via vSphere from my local network
but can't connect from internet. Some people http://www.logicalsolutions.co.nz/connect-vsphere-client-externally/ achived by port forwarding so did i.

```
ESXi settings
ip 192.168.100.118
mask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.100.1

Router settings
incoming port 443 forwarded to 443 of server 192.168.100.118 (my ESXi)
incoming port 902 forwarded to 902 of server 192.168.100.118 (my ESXi)
```

vSphere "public ip":port

still no connection.

So i thought if the problem was with router and forwarded some port to my local sqlserver port. It works

Maybe there are some settings where can i enable public access to ESXi.

Comment: for connect to esxi remotely you have two solution.

1. if you use Esxi 6.5 its has WebConsole client instead of vsphereClient that you can connect to it remotely on port 80.

2. you can connect via ssh on port 22 that dpcument in this [link][1]


  [1]: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjoheLB2_jXAhUsKMAKHa37DioQFggkMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpubs.vmware.com%2Fvsphere-51%2Ftopic%2Fcom.vmware.vcli.getstart.doc%2Fcli_jumpstart.3.6.html&usg=AOvVaw25KUp4__WWuBmHQsfsmZnW

Answer (score 0):

I made some work-around to make it be possible with vcenter server (except for the consoles to the VMs):

- I configured my local computer to identify itself as "vcenter-server-name" and "vcenter-server-name.full.qualified.domain.name"
  in linux it is basically add this names to the `hosts` file near the local address:

  ```
  127.0.0.1    localhost.localdomain vcenter-server-name.full.qualified.domain.name vcenter-server-name
  ```
- I created a tunnel to the vcenter server via a host in the remote network that I can ssh to. the sudo is because of using local 443 port:

  `sudo ssh myuserneme@access-able.host.name -L 443:vcenter-server-name:443`

after these steps, I have had access to all the links and JS/watsnot that used FQDN.

In case the ESXi host recognizes itself only by its IP address and does not have a domain name, you won't be able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

for connect to esxi remotely you have two solution.

1. if you use Esxi 6.5 its has WebConsole client instead of vsphereClient that you can connect to it remotely on port 80.
2. you can connect via ssh on port 22 that dpcument in this [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjoheLB2_jXAhUsKMAKHa37DioQFggkMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpubs.vmware.com%2Fvsphere-51%2Ftopic%2Fcom.vmware.vcli.getstart.doc%2Fcli_jumpstart.3.6.html&usg=AOvVaw25KUp4__WWuBmHQsfsmZnW)

Answer (score 0):

better solution is to use  using the vSphere Update Manager to upgrade Esxi hosts.

that need to exist an VCenter server.

or on the console bash (with esx cli) use update command:

```
esxcli software profile update -d https://hostupdate.vmware.com/software/VUM/PRODUCTION/main/vmw-depot-index.xml -p ESXi-6.5.0-20170702001-standard
```